# Run 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS beta test version

Tags: raspbian-buster, 64-bit, raspberry-pi-os

With the latest release from 2020-05-27 the [operating system was renamed from **Raspbian** to **Raspberry Pi OS**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and its image names are changed from e.g. `2020-02-13-raspbian-buster.zip` to `2020-05-27-raspios-buster-armhf.zip`, with the postfix **-armhf**. This implies that there could also be a version with **-arm64**.

If this is true, where can I find, install and run this 64 bit version of the Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: I have 64-bit Raspberry OS running in front of me now, the download instructions are [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=275370). I've flashed a card as normal with no problems, save one package (Mathematica) will not as yet install.

Comment: Sounds more like using a pipeline that uses this convention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the image of the **64 bit Raspberry Pi OS** at

- https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

You can download and flash it to a SD Card like any other image of the operating system. You should be able to run it on a RasPi that supports 64 bit. As far as I know, these are RPi 3B, 3B+, and 4B. There may be others, please give me a note.

But if you boot it, it hangs and just do nothing. This is because a Raspberry Pi loads a 32 bit kernel by default. You have to tell it to use the 64 bit kernel `/boot/kernel8.img`. This can be done with an entry in `/boot/config.txt`. Just mount the **fat** (boot) partition of the fresh flashed SD Card, attached to your "flashing machine", and add this line to it:

```
kernel=kernel8.img
```

and have fun with 64 bit :-)

**Update:**
The link to the forum thread [Raspberry Pi OS (64 bit) beta test version](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=275370), given by *@Nick* in his comment (thanks to Nick), says what it is. As you can read there, it has some limitations and it is [not official propagated](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

> **Known issues** at 2020-06-02
>   1. There is no hardware video acceleration in VLC or Chromium
>    2. libraspberrypi0, libraspberrypi-dev and libraspberrypi-doc have been moved out of /opt/vc/* and into /usr/* instead (making it more standard). Any code built against these libraries will require changing to refer to a more standard location (/usr/lib/ rather than /opt/vc/lib)
>    3. Due to 2) Many packages that expect libGLESv2.so libEGL etc will require rebuilding.
>    4. raspberrypi-bootloader and raspberrypi-kernel contain useless non-64bit binaries and is missing the work done to minimise the delay between files being deleted and installed to /boot
>    5. There is no Wolfram Mathematica built for AArch64
>    6. Minecraft shim layer requires rebuilding to cope with 2)
>    7. VLC needs rebuild (not available)
>    8. VNC server not rebuilt yet for 64bit

Comment: What advantages have you noticed with the 64-bit OS?

Comment: The compute modules are also 64bit

Comment: @Seamus I can direct address more than 4GB without big numbers ;-) No, but it is a very popular request of many people, something like the must have a static ip address.

Comment: @Swedgin Yes, the link will be obsolete in a couple of months like any other version, but I think it will be accessable like any other obsolete version.

Comment: @Swedgin Done. Good idea, thanks.

Comment: This hang sounds strange. Is this a known bug? Or is the image simply not of release quality?

Comment: @Ruslan I have updated the answer.