# Alpine Linux architecture for Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: pi-4, cpu

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I need to install a 64-bit operating system for my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, in order to install the latest version of MongoDB.

I am wondering about which architecture I should use:

1. ARMhf
2. AArch64
3. ARMv7

---

This is the CPU:
**Broadcom BCM2711, Quad-Core ARM Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.5GHz**

Comment: You're mixing your terms. 32-bit is ARMhf, 64-bit is AArch64. ARMv7 is the processor model on the RPi2B.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 1):

Just some days ago the Raspberry Pi foundation has released its first 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS test version. You may give it a try. At time it has some limitations but I think this does not effect MongoDB.

With this operating system you can be sure that it is supported and improved in the future. How to use it you can look at [Run 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS beta test version](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113048/79866).

Answer (score 0):

aarch64 is the architecture my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B uses but you can tell by using uname or lscpu (I'm using linux).

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the latest version of MongoDB, you will need to compile from source by yourself because there are no officially supported binaries for the Pi platform.

I have posted cross-compilation instructions, along with binaries (much easier and quicker) that I have tested here: https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries