# How to install mongodb in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, mongodb

I have tried to install the one from apt, but that was really old

So I tried to go to mongo website and download the newest version

but then I get this isse:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-server:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.18) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libcurl3:arm64 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libgcc1:arm64 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libssl1.0.0:arm64 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

why is this not installable?
any suggestion?

Comment: Latest MongoDB is 64-bit only. Plain RaspiOS is 32-bit. The 64-bit Raspbian is still in beta testing. You will need to switch to a supported 64-bit operating system.

Comment: arm64?  Is that the correct architecture for Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: Once you have a 64-bit OS installed, you can use these pre-built MongoDB binaries:
https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Raspbian. This is only built with a 32 bit architecture `armhf`. I seems you have downloaded MongoDB with the 64 bit architecture `arm64`. You cannot run 64 bit programs on a 32 bit architecture. You either have to use a 32 bit MongoDB or use a 64 bit operating system. There is a [64 bit Raspberry Pi OS in beta test](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113048/79866). You can try to use that.