# Will Docker install on Raspbian OS 64bit

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit

I have installed docker on Raspbian Stretch using the install script `get-docker.sh`, but am having difficulty installing on 64bit Raspbian OS

The install script terminates with

```
sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I run docker version I get

```
sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a6621
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:47:06 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
```

Is the docker daemon running?

and docker info gives a similar error

Is it one more application that wont run on 64bit? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that my be the case. The only other application I know won't run yet is Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi OS 64bit and the Docker Engine are flagged to be Experimental. You should not expect to get a stable installation. And yes, there are of course more applications that wont run on 64bit. You should find hints on the release notes what's not working so far.

Here you will find known issues at 2020-06-02: [Run 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS beta test version](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113048/79866). Don't know what's fixed till now.